# Как в haproxy сделать редирект с http на https?

Tags: redirect, proxy, https, ssl

Пробую как в мануале делать. https://serversforhackers.com/using-ssl-certificates-with-haproxy

Работает, если по https:// заходить. Если по http то выдает:

```
Bad Request 
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.
```

Как сделать редирект с http на https?

Вот конфиг

```
frontend myfrontend
bind *:80
bind *:443
option tcplog
mode tcp
default_backend nodes
backend nodes
mode tcp
balance roundrobin
option ssl-hello-chk
server web01 *.*.*.*:443 check
```